# django rest serialize level 2 field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Hi I need to add a field in a serializer of a 2 level reference item.

I have the following model:

model.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
   companyName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class Poll(models.Model):
   questionString = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
   companyId = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, db_column='companyId', blank=True)

class PossibleAnswer(models.Model):
   answerString = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
   pollId = models.ForeignKey(Poll, null=True, db_column='pollId', blank=True,related_name='answers')
   token = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

serializers.py:

```
class PossibleAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   #companyId = serializers.RelatedField()
   class Meta:
       model = PossibleAnswer
       fields = ('answerString', 'token', 'pollId', 'companyId')
```

I want to make a Serializer for the PossibleAnswer object that has a field named company. How to make a this reference? Something similar to: pollId__companyId in a django query set filter.

Comment: it's not a good idea to name your Django fkey field `pollId`—the field will contain a `Poll` object, not an ID.

Comment: Do you need to write to the field or read only?

Comment: I think, it can be a read only. I need to used companyId to created a custom permission to check if a certain user can create a PossibleAnswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the field is read-only you can easily achieve this with a `serializers.Field`, which accept dotted paths to the source.

Your Serializer would be:

```
class PossibleAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    companyId = serializers.Field(source='pollId.companyId')
    class Meta:
        model = PossibleAnswer
        fields = ('answerString', 'token', 'pollId', 'companyId')
```

I too agree with Erik, that naming model attributes with `Id` is a bad idea even though the DB representation is only the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution...

```
class PossibleAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   companyId = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_companyId(self, obj):
        return obj.pollId.companyId

   class Meta:
       model = PossibleAnswer
       fields = ('answerString', 'token', 'pollId', 'companyId',)
```